# How can I pass variables to multiple objects in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the Main camera has "variable1" from Script1

```
public int variable1;
```

multiple cubes that will be instance created will share Script2 that has "variable2"

```
public int variable2;
```

I tried using this as a way to get the variable when it needed it, Which is not on start or awake but through a specific action.

```
public int variable2;  // on the cube
public GameObject mainCamera; // I set this in the editor
public void main() {
    variable2 = mainCamera.GetComponent <cameraScript> ().variable1;
}
```

How can I set variable2 without referencing a specific one since I will have a lot of them? Can I do it with tags?

Comment: what do you meen by "without referencing a specific one" ?

Comment: If they all have the same value, but get that value from somewhere else (your camerascript), just keep a reference to that camerascript and use it's variable.

Comment: "to get the variable when it needed it the thing it variable other varaible the script the it thing" - you desperately need to start describing your code in concrete, specific terms, or you'll never complete your game. You cannot program with variables named "variable"! ... and it's almost impossible for anyone to help with your code, because it's incoherent: the names are confusing and meaningless.

Comment: @Amin_it like chess pieces, I don't want to call assign a variable to "pawn.1033" since there are a bunch.

Comment: @GunnarB. I tried that, if you look above to where variable2 is assigned, you can see how I did it.

Comment: @Adam I am referencing "variable1" and "variable2" because this is not my game and I am under strict non-disclosure agreements. Let me re-iterate for you. White pawns in chess need to know that they are pawns, correct? Let's say they need to know how much they can move.  Now, what if the amount pawns can move will change. That's why it's on the camera and not the "cube" or the "pawn". It's inefficient code to repeatedly assign to high numbers of objects. I tried getting it like above and I was wrong so I asked for help.

Comment: I meant to not actually create your `variable2`, but only have a `private CameraScript camScript` and then call `camScript.variable1` when you need to know the value. This way you can have a centralized spot where all your information is and give each indivual object a link to that (e.g. set it after instantiation).

Comment: Btw., you can create empty gameobjects. I'd recommend to use one of those to hold your scripts and not put them on your camera if the camera isn't actually related to that script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to change the value of variable2 in all cube at once? I assume you want to make this variable2's value to be uniform.

If yes, why don't you make your variable2 as a **static** variable? As it will share the value between  your *Script2* classes throughout your project.

For example,

On your Script2.cs:

```
public static int variable2;
```

So you can change the value of variable2 for all the cubes within your sample script in one line:

```
Script2.variable2 = mainCamera.GetComponent <cameraScript> ().variable1;
```

Comment: Well yes and no, think of it like a Civilization  or command and conquer game if you have ever seen one. I will have a bunch of objects that could need the info from variable1 but don't have to have it unless it is "active" i guess you could say. If I could change many cubes, i can't have it effect other cubes with the same script but with different tags, variables, and properties that don't need it. The reason it isn't static is that I was under the impression that you can't change a static variable. Both need to be able to change, or be assigned multiple times.

Comment: @MikeSmith `static` means it (e.g. the value of the variable) is part of the class, not a specific instance of the class. It can be changed easily. A variable can't be changed if it is `const`.

Comment: Alright, I created an empty and hid it behind the camera. I gave it the Script2. I made variable2 a public static. I went into Script1 on the camera and added some lines:
public GameObject cube; // assigned in editor
cube.GetComponent <cubeScript> ().variable2 = variable1;

Comment: @MikeSmith If it is really _public static_, actually there is no need for `GetComponent<cubeScript>().variable2` to access variable2. You can simply access it through `cubeScript.variable2` and assign it with variable1. Variables with _static_ modifier means the variable is not just belong to an object but shared to all objects of the class, and the example before is how you access them.  I think you might want to refresh your concept a bit about C#'s _static variables_.

Comment: Hm, didn't know that. I'll use that then.